# Eclipse slow. It does not even work

Tags: eclipse

I have installed a new eclipse with a relatively small Jhipster project. And it's going so slow that it's practically impossible to work and I'm desperate.

Eclipse version:

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)
Build id: 20171005-1200
OS: Linux, v.4.10.0-42-generic, x86_64 / gtk 3.18.9, WebKit 2.4.11

Constantly leave the following messages:

"Remoste System Explorer Oporation"
"JPA Project Change Event Handler"
"Linking viewer selection with current editor"

I have done the following to try to correct it, without success:

Eclipse -> Preferences -> Remote Systems.

Uncheck Re-open Remote Systems view to previous state.

Eclipse -> Preferences -> Validation

Enable All

My .ini file is original, I do not know if I can improve there, since I have 32 of Ram:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
/home/jose/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.550.v20170928-1359
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
```

Information about my computer:

```
System:    Host: xxxx Kernel: 4.10.0-42-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.4.0)
       Desktop: Cinnamon 3.4.6 (Gtk 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3) dm: mdm Distro: Linux Mint 18.2 Sonya
Machine:   Mobo: ASUSTeK model: P8Z77-V LX v: Rev X.0x Bios: American Megatrends v: 2204 date: 08/14/2013
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i7-3770 (-HT-MCP-) cache: 8192 KB
       flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 28021
       clock speeds: min/max: 1600/4100 MHz 1: 4099 MHz 2: 4099 MHz 3: 4099 MHz 4: 4099 MHz
       5: 4100 MHz 6: 4098 MHz 7: 4099 MHz 8: 4099 MHz
```

Comment: Did you follow this link http://www.jhipster.tech/configuring-ide-eclipse/ ? With IntelliJ, I need to exclude node_modules, otherwise, it's too slow.

Comment: I have done all the steps you indicate and it remains the same. :(

Comment: Are you **required** to use Eclipse? Can you switch to **Netbeans** or **IntelliJ IDEA**? I don't know about the latter, but I know Netbeans 8.2 runs perfectly fine with only 2G ram.

Comment: I recently updgraded to the 10-2018 eclipse, and first saw this error, and then updated to what is the latest and greatest, and also see this error. Possible issue: "The UI often freezes after doing something (I'm working mainly with Java, XML and XHTML files). When this happens, it often causes the "Linking viewer selection with current editor" task to last several seconds.
_  https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=530450

Answer (score 2):

Please increasing these values and restarting eclipse :

```
-Xms256m ->-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m ->Xmx2048m
```